# How to generate Cucumber Report using Main.run method?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber for Java

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am not using `Cucumber Options` to configure the step or feature to use. I am using `Main.run` method

```
String feature = "/resources/service1/feature1.feature"
Main.run(new String[]{"--glue", "example.aop.testing.steps", feature}
            , Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
```

Everything it's working find but I would like to generate a report with the result. I was reading about it and to configura it I need to use `Cucumber Options`, like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@Cucumber.Options(format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}) 

public class runTest { }
```

How can I configure it using that approach??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other options in the same array you are adding your glue and feature like below

```
 String[] commonOptions = {
                "--glue",
                "com.test.automation.stepdefinitions",
                "--tags",
                "@foo",                
                "--plugin",
                "pretty",
                "--plugin",
                "html:"+reportFolderPath+"/html",
                "--plugin",
                "json:"+reportFolderPath+"/cucumber.json",
                FEATURE_FILE_PATH
        };
```

Comment: ``"html:"+reportFolderPath+"/html",`` is generation a file without extension, and it should be creating a folder with the reporting